# Anova interpretation of F-statistics

Tags: r, anova

I am having trouble trying to interpret the differences between what the F value and the Pr(>F) values are between the treatments below.

For context,

null hypothesis: treatment_B has no significant impact on treatment_A

alt hypothesis: treatment_B has sgnificant impact on treatment_A

I am also wondering what "treatment_A:treatment_B" means?

[image: screenshot of results]

Answer (score 3):

The F-value is the actual F-statistic that is calculated for each component in your model.  `Pr(>F)` is your p-value for each component.  `treatment_A:treatment_B` is an interaction term.  Looking at the formula you used in `aov()`, you have `treatment_A * treatment_B` which means that `treatment_A` and `treatment_B` will each enter into the model independently, but also an interaction term (`treatment_A:treatment_B`) is entered.  The interaction term is the product of those two terms.

Comment: +1 but I would like to add a hint to the help page accessible via `help("formula")`. Knowing about the `*` and `:` and `I()`s is essential for R users and the OP should take some time to really "get it".

Comment: @Bernhard - thanks for the edits (much improved!) and very good addition with the help("formula") link.